# Grid list as expansion panel header

Tags: angular-material

I need expansion panel to show header as columns. I wanted to use grid list component for that, but when I place it the header shows empty. Any way to achieve that?

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-grid-list cols="3">
      <mat-grid-tile colspan="1">Column 1</mat-grid-tile>
      <mat-grid-tile colspan="1">Column 2</mat-grid-tile>
      <mat-grid-tile colspan="1">Column 3</mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <p>Some content</p>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component mat-grid-list is actually there but it's invisible because the width is zero. So applying the styles as below to the component will work.

```css
mat-grid-list {
  width: 100%;
}
```